# How to research facilities/ratings of US airport lounges online?

Tags: usa, online-resources, airports, lounges

For an upcoming trip, it looks like for my US departure I'll have access to more than one airport lounge. (One via FF status, a different via a credit card). This is a nice position to be in, but rather than treking round the airport from lounge to lounge to investigate them, I figured I ought to be able to get some idea about them in advance.

Finding out what lounges are in a given airport is usually straightforward, as the airport website tends to list them. Finding out if you can get access to a given lounge is a little bit trickier, but between the lounge's website and that of the airline and any credit cards you can normally get the answer. (The trickier queries probably warrant their own questions though!) What the lounges are like, and what facilities they have is the bit that's eluding me...

Within Europe, airport lounges tend to all have a fairly high common standard, with a few (typically flagship ones in the carriers home airport) proving amazing. In America, I've found the quality and facilities to vary dramatically, from shockingly basic to poor-European standard. Ideally I'd like to make a beeline for one of the latter given a choice, rather than the former!

I figure there probably are resources out there which list the facilities on offer (is there free wifi, are there free newspapers, are there free soft drinks, what about snacks, meals, alcoholic drinks etc). Possibly also rating them on decor and furnishings too, though I'm less worried about that. I'm not sure where to find such things though.

So, I'm wondering, how best should I go about researching the facilities and catering of American airport lounges online? Any good website or resources out there?

Comment: Wow I was positive somebody already asked this question but I can't see it...

Comment: We've had questions on lounge access eligibility, and on a few non-US lounges, but I don't think we've had anything like this so far

Comment: http://www.airlinequality.com/Product/Lounges.htm That one has reviews... It's the only one I have ever used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of options that a search throws up:

- [LoungeGuide](http://www.loungeguide.net/wiki/u/Main_Page): A wiki website with user contributions on facilities at airport lounges.
- [Lounges.net](http://www.lounges.net): Coverage outside US/EU seems spotty, but otherwise seems to have useful, helpful reviews (looking at EU airports I have been to, and general quality of written reviews).