# Any daytime airport hotel at JFK airport (New York)?

Tags: layovers, hotels, jfk, lounges

I have a 9-hour layover at JFK (New York). From 10 am until 7 pm (although I have to check in at 3 pm for personal reasons).

This being in the middle of a 2-day travel, I would love to take a break to shower and rest a bit. How can I do that for cheap?

I have 3 pieces of luggage and 2 carry-on, if it matters...

Comment: 10 AM to 7 PM is a 9 hour layover.

Comment: Good point, typo :) However I have to check in 4 hours ahead as this is a group flight.

Answer (score 7):

I discovered that option by reading this website: airport lounges sometimes offer good and reasonably priced solutions to rest.

Two questions could have relevant answers:
[one about what the different lounges offer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-research-facilities-ratings-of-us-airport-lounges-online) and [one about how to get there for cheap](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7744/free-cheap-ways-to-get-airport-lounge-access)

EDIT: with the PriorityPass, as you mention you have it, the KAL lounge requires you to have a boarding pass to enter. The United Club has conditions on how you got your card (if it's from your bank you can't) and the Oasis lounge allows you to stay no more than 3 hours. In the end these conditions are annoying but I think you can make it.

Comment: I have PriorityPass so the lougne solution looked good. However I am worry they won't let me in until I have checked-in...

Comment: are you sure, I think the point of lounges is for layovers. Well at least that's how I imagine it, maybe indeed the point is to make money and let people pay for services they can't use.

Answer (score 3):

I have a very similar JFK layover coming up - I've researched the question a bit, and here's what I could find:

- [Between9and5 website](https://www.between9and5.com/) lets you search for "day rates" at hotels near airports. There are a few options listed for JFK at around $75 for a 10am-to-3pm stay.
- Apparently you can find the best "day rates" by calling hotels near the airport directly (not the 800 number but the direct hotel number). The best "day rates" are often released in the morning (i.e. you can't book them in advance).
- Lounges vary in their "sleeper-friendliness". For example, the official United lounge policy forbids sleeping (I don't know whether this is enforced). On the other hand, the flagship Delta lounge in Terminal 4 of JFK has a special "relaxation room", and the policy makes no mention of sleeping (that I could find). Lots of lounges also offer showers.
- [Another website about sleeping near airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/) may also be a good resource
- Some people recommend getting an overnight hotel rate the night before, with late checkout (e.g. 3pm), and then calling the hotel to say that you'll arrive in the morning. Apparently Priceline works well for this.