# Single room in a hotel for a party of 4 if we check out in the evening?

Tags: hotels, italy, milan

I'll be arriving in Milan, Italy by train from Rome around 12:00 and have to leave for the airport at around 21:00 the same day. I'm with my family of 4 and thought of booking a hotel room essentially just to keep the luggage there and to use the WC.

Do you think it would be possible to book just a single room for that purpose?  Or that the Hotel would frown upon it?

Comment: Also you can check Airport lounges that are designed for this purpose, but it might be way more expensive. Related question : http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10190/what-are-the-choices-of-cost-effective-lounges-at-european-airports

Comment: I'd rather spend the day in Milan than Malpensa, the architecture at least should be more interesting!  I'll probably just book the cheapest hotel adjacent to the central train station.

Comment: Yeah, good indeed. But why not using the airports toilets and the lockers then? http://www.airwise.com/airports/europe/milan_mxp/luggage.html

Comment: Because I'd rather stay in Milan.  So I'd need a hotel/luggage storage near the Central station in Milan.  I just checked and you can get very cheap ok hotels there which should suffice for the day.

Comment: I'm not sure you read my comment. It meant, if you get a locker in the airport, you can leave there your luggage and then go to Milan for the day. A locker is cheaper than a hotel (I suppose you don't have that much luggage at least).

Comment: I probably should have clarified my statement better:  I'm arriving by train from Rome to Milan, so I won't be at Malpensa (airport) until I leave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would really depend on the hotel, and their terms and conditions.  More than likely, you'll probably be charged for a full night as the hotel will find it hard to sell the room once you all depart.

Comment: There is no question that I would pay that full night price.  I was more worried if they'd make some fuss because we are 4 and only paying for a single room.

Comment: I would say so, as often, hotel rooms charge extra per extra person.  Furthermore, they could get in trouble with the authorities if they have on their books that they allowed a party of 4 to occupy a single room (safety regulations).

Comment: You're most welcome, and safe journeys!

Comment: The Sheraton hotel in Milan that is connected to Terminal 1 offers a day use package specifically for this situation, but you have to vacate the room before 18:00 to get the discount: http://deals.sheraton.com/Sheraton-Milan-Malpensa-Airport-Hotel-3138/so.htm

Answer (score 6):

Milano Centrale station has a [left luggage office(http://www.milanocentrale.it/en/service/detail/left-luggage1); for 9 hours the fee is €7.80. There are of course [toilets](http://www.milanocentrale.it/en/service/index/restrooms) (with a €1 fee), but unfortunately [no shower](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g187849-i143-k5690656-Shower_etc_during_short_stopover_at_Milano_Centrale-Milan_Lombardy.html). It seems that there is a [wifi hotspot too](http://www.raileurope.co.uk/Default.aspx?tabid=1120), I can't find any information as to whether it's free.

While there are [hotels in Milan with day rooms](http://www.dayguest.com/milan-dayuse), you'd have to vacate the room by 18:00 at the latest. It doesn't seem worthwhile unless you really want to sleep.