# When is OSL lounge at Gardermoen Airport full/unavailable for paid-access passengers?

Tags: airports, lounges

**OSL Lounge** [[1](https://www.yelp.com/biz/osl-lounge-gardermoen),[2](https://avinor.no/en/airport/oslo-airport/plan-your-trip/lounge/)] is the only one of the four lounges in Oslo (Gardermoen) Airport which allows passengers from non-member airlines (or any Norwegian Airlines passengers below Premium Flex) paid access for NOK350(/€35/US$40) from 3 hours before departure.  (FYI: a) It is not a member of PremiumPass b) It is the only non-SAS lounge, and SAS lounges don't do paid-access to the general public c) (I had never heard of DragonPass but OSL Lounge is apparently available for US$50 on it [[3](https://en.dragonpass.com.cn/lounge/303521)]), but I only found that out a month later).

At least OSL Lounge claims it allows paid access. However when I tried to pay to get into it recently (Wednesday July 3, 2019) they told me they were full that entire day so I couldn't. Not even "come back and try later". There was no sign reflecting that, and nothing on their website either. I asked them what days and times they tended to be unavailable, and they couldn't tell me, and didn't seem in the least bothered by that. (Yay, 8hr stopovers).

**My question is: what days/times/months is OSL Lounge full/unavailable to paid-access passengers?**